# jQuery .after not adding elements in IE7/IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong and there isn't any indication this shouldn't work in IE. But the following code doesn't add the `<dd>` elements in .after() to the DOM:

```
shouts_list_selector = $("#shouts dl#shouts_list");

shout_object = $('<dt>')
            .attr('id', shout.id)
            .text(shout.name)
            .append($('<span>').addClass('separator').text(' : '))
            .append($('<abbr>').addClass('timestamp').attr('title', shout.timestamp).text(shout.when))
            .after($('<dd>').html(shout.message))

shout_object.prependTo(shouts_list_selector).slideDown('slow', 'swing');
```

shouts is an object containing some messages. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome. But IE is missing the `<dd>`elements. Is there anything wrong with this example or a better way to do it?

Edit: Here is an example showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/sx6YH/

The DD tags show correctly when run in Firefox or Chrome. But not in IE.

Comment: perhaps `$('<dd></dd>').html('shout message')` ???

Comment: @experimentx, jquery creates a new element when passed a string opening tag, so the closing tag is not necessary.

Comment: @nathanconzalez and about the `$().emoticon(shout.message)` ???

Comment: @experimentx, looks to be some sort of extension, probably to parse the message and add smileys and what have you.

Comment: @nathangonzalez well i guess the same, but he says that it's not working, means that it's being appended but .. no html means no display.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to remove the emoticon part from the code. It is an external function that turns emoticon text into images. When defining a new element the same way for the `<dt>` it includes the proper closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by just creating the `<dd>` tag and `appendingTo` the list right after the `<dt>` like so:

```
shouts_list = $('<dl>').attr('id', 'shouts_list');

$.each(shouts_object.shouts, function(id, shout) {
    $('<dt>')
        .attr('id', shout.id)
        .text(shout.name)
        .append($('<span>')
                .text(' : '))
        .append($('<abbr>')
                .attr('title', shout.timestamp)
                .text(shout.when))
        .appendTo(shouts_list);
    $('<dd>').html(shout.message)
        .appendTo(shouts_list);
});

shouts_list.appendTo('#shouts');
```

This works fine in both IE8 and Firefox. I feel like there may be a bug in IE8 with handling `.after`

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason of this is a nested append. IE8 doesn't seem to be able to handle those correctly. I had this same problem, @Andy Shinn put me in the right direction. In my case I was trying to add a link to an unsorted list:

```
<ul id=menu></ul>
```

with the following jQuery:

```
$("ul[id=menu]").append("<li><a href='test.html'>test</a></li>");
```

This works in most browsers, but *not* in IE8. If you add them unnested it does work:

```
$("ul[id=menu]").append("<li/>").html("<a href='test.html'>test</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason the `<dd>` elements are not displayed is because you are creating invalid html. with your current code the html is resolved to :

```
<dt id="1">
    test
    <span class="separator"> : </span>
</dt>
<dd>hello</dd>
```

the `<dd>` should obviously be inside the `<dt>`.

your code should look like this:

```
shout_object = $('<dt>')
        .attr('id', shout.id)
        .text(shout.name)
        .append($('<span>').addClass('separator').text(' : '))
        .append($('<abbr>').addClass('timestamp').attr('title', shout.timestamp).text(shout.when))
        .append($('<dd>').html($().emoticon(shout.message)))
```

then your html will be fine and render in ie7/8

Comment: According to the standard it looks like the `<dd>` tag should be outside the tag and not inside the `<dt>` tag. `<dt>` is the term (name in this case) and `<dd>` is the message. Also to note, using .after the code code (invalid or note) doesn't seem to get inserted into the DOM (when viewing with IE debugging tools).